# ES2015 modules vs ES5 globals determined by 'export' keyword?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm reading about `ES2015` modules and trying to make sure I understand this new feature.

Since there's nothing like `"use strict"`, how does the browser determine that a .js file is an `ES2015` module v.s. an `ES5` file with a bunch of globals? Is it just by the presence of at least one "`export`" statement?

---

```
// This file is interpreted as ES5 with globals
function fun1() {...}
function fun1() {...}
```

---

```
// This file is interpreted as ES2015 module
function fun1() {...}
function fun1() {...}
export default function(){...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since there's nothing like "use strict", how does the browser determine that a .js file is an ES2015 module v.s. an ES5 file with a bunch of globals? Is it just by the presence of at least one "export" statement?

When you asked this question, it hadn't been decided, but it was a couple of years later: The [`type`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-type) attribute is used:

```
<script type="module" src="./mod.js"></script>
```

You also need to include a path (not just `src="mod.js"`), unless you use a [import map](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps) (which is relatively new as of this writing in July 2019, and I don't think any browser supports them natively yet).

If you use `import` or `export` in something that isn't a module, you'll get a syntax error.

---

In Node.js, which has its own CommonJS-like (CJS) module system, ECMAScript Modules (ESM) are signified in one of two ways:

1. By having `"type": "module"` in the nearest `package.json`, or
2. By giving the script the extension `.mjs` instead of `.js`.

(If the nearest `package.json` has `"type": "module"`, you can still have a script that's a CJS module by giving it the extension `.cjs`.) Details [here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://www.2ality.com/2013/11/es6-modules-browsers.html), modules can't go inside `script` tags, they must go inside `module` tags. So code loaded by `script` tags can't be treated as modules, and code loaded by `module` tags must be a module.

Comment: There is not even a draft for the `<module>` tag is it?

Comment: @zerkms: No, [not yet](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#elements-3).